# Return updated value of variable in java recursion

Tags: java

I want to verify whether a name contains special characters or not. Please let me know what's wrong with this code? My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Name {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String verifyName() {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
        if(!m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Name");
            verifyName();
        }
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String result = verifyName();
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter your name: @li
Invalid Name
Enter your name: #sd
Invalid Name
Enter your name: Zain
@li
```

**Required Output:**

```
Enter your name: @li
Invalid Name
Enter your name: #sd
Invalid Name
Enter your name: Zain
Zain
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're clearly missing some code here - namely what prints the last line of output. Given your title, it seems to me that your method should *return* something. I don't think I'd use recursion for this either - just use a loop.

Comment: You use recursion, but only for the case that you entered an invalid name. Are you sure that this is what you want to do? For thouse cases, I would recommend a `do { ... } while (...)`-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole code should be like

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Name {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String verifyName() {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
        if (!m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Name");
            return verifyName();
        }
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String result = verifyName();
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

For efficiency you may use iterative loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs to return the value of the name from the sub-function call

```
if(!m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Name");
    return verifyName();
}
```

instead of

```
if(!m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Name");
    verifyName();
}
```

however it may be better to use a loop instead of a recursive call:

```
public static String verifyName() {
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
        if(m.matches()) {
           return name;
        }
    }
```

}